# Getting top-center of a sprite, adjusted for rotation?

Tags: math, rotation, sprite

I have a small square sprite, and I need to get the top center of the sprite based on rotation.

Here's an image describing what I want:

[image]

The left sprite is the sprite at it's natural position, and the other sprites are rotated. The black dot's position is what I want to get (the position on the sprite).

I know this is probably a dumb question achieved with a basic knowledge of trig, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, here's my solution:

```
x = (float) (PlayerEntity.getPos().x + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(PlayerEntity.getAngle())));
y = (float) (PlayerEntity.getPos().y + Math.sin(Math.toRadians(PlayerEntity.getAngle())));
```